# Expected value of HGeom

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have this paragraph in my book.

**(Hypergeometric expectation). Let $X \sim HGeom(w, b, n)$, interpreted as the number of white balls in a sample of size $n$ drawn without replacement from an urn with $w$ white and $b$ black balls. As in the Binomial case, we can write $X$ as a sum of Bernoulli random variables,
$X = I_1 + · · · + I_n$,
where $I_j$ equals 1 if the $j$th ball in the sample is white and 0 otherwise. By symmetry,
$I_j ∼ Bernoulli(p)$ with $p = w/(w+b)$, since unconditionally the $j$th ball drawn is equally likely to be any of the balls.
Unlike in the Binomial case, the $I_j$ are not independent, since the sampling is without replacement: given that a ball in the sample is white, there is a lower chance that another ball in sample will be white.**

I am aware that to measure expected value of $X$, linearity of expectation is used. But one thing I am not understanding is that why every indicator variable is provided probability $w/(w+b)$ it's clear that's not a case they are dependent on each other, and their probability must vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of the linearity property of expectation is that it doesn't matter at all if the terms are correlated.  The expectation of a sum equals the sum of the expectations.  Independence is not a requirement, and that is what makes it such a powerful and useful statement in probability theory.

If $S = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$, then $$\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[X_1] + \operatorname{E}[X_2] + \cdots + \operatorname{E}[X_n],$$ so long as each of these expected values exists.

In the hypergeometric case, the indicator variables are indeed correlated as you point out, but because this doesn't matter for the expectation of their sum, it suffices to apply linearity and observe that the marginal distribution for each indicator variable in the sum must be Bernoulli distributed, and moreover, must be identically distributed with the same success parameter--this is because the order of the indicator variables does not matter.

You are conceptualizing the draws as occurring sequentially:  you pick one ball, observe its color, then pick the next one, observe its color, etc.  But this is not at all a necessary aspect of the sampling process.  For instance, you could reach in without looking, and take out $n$ balls, then still without looking, arrange them in a neat line.  Then you open your eyes and read off the sequence of colors from left to right.  The sampling occurred without replacement and all at once, because once the balls were arranged in a line, their colors became fixed and determined, although you had yet to observe them.  Observing the first ball's color in that line would not affect the probability distribution of the subsequent balls' colors.